# how to validate after checkboxed clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I broke my Code down to make it look  simple

```js
  const [factor, setfactor] = useState(1);
  const [nullify, setNullify] = useState(1);

  const Price = 10;
  const Bonus = 15;
  const finalPrice = (Price * factor - Bonus) * nullify;
// start         5 = (10 * 2 -15)* 1
// after Click  -5 = (10 * 1 -15)* 1
//what i want    0 = (10 * 1 -15)* 0

   const handleFactor = () => {
    setfactor(1)
    validate()
  };

  const validate = () => {
    if (finalPrice <= 0) {
      setNullify(0);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleFactor();
  }, [factor]);
  //HTML Stuff
  return (
    <>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleFactor} />
      <input type="checkbox" onClick="activate bonus" />


      {finalPrice}
    </>
  );
```

I want, if the bonus make it below 0 the final price should not be a minus number , instead it should becomes a zero itself - but it doesn't work.

I know, that the final price will be 5 when the validation do it's thing. But how do I get the newPrice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous, so you can get the updated state on the next render. When you do this

```
const handleFactor = () => {
  setfactor(1)
  validate()
};
```

the state haven't updated yet, and validate would use the previous (valid) values. You'll need to move validate to the next render for this to work.

However, you don't need another state to ensure that `finalPrice` is above `0`. Use Math.max(price * factor - bonus, 0)`to get the max between the final price and`0` (or any other minimum number):

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React;

const Demo = ({ price, bonus }) => {
  const [factor, setfactor] = useState(2);

  const finalPrice = Math.max(price * factor - bonus, 0);

  const handleFactor = () => {
    setfactor(1)
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleFactor} />
      {finalPrice}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo price={10} bonus={15} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```